# Since "User-defined conversions to or from a derived class are not allowed," is there a decent alternative in my situation?

Tags: c#, .net

My surveying application has a class Vector inheriting from class Matrix which exposes operations appropriate to 1D vector-type matrices. Forseeably someone will try to downcast a Matrix to a Vector even though the underlying array isn't 1-dimensional. Then they won't know there's a problem until an exception occurs down the road in one of the Vector operations. But if I try to implement a cast, viz:

```
public static explicit operator Vector3(Matrix m)
{
   if (m.Array.GetLength(0) != 3 && m.Array.GetLength(1) != 1)
       throw new InvalidCastException("The matrix dimensions are invalid.");
   return new Vector3(m[0, 0], m[1, 0], m[2, 0]);
}
```

I get the exception of the title. Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type hierarchy is problematic. `Vector` should not be inheriting from `Matrix` in the first place -- this is another take on the classic [circle/ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

In addition, casting a `Matrix` to a `Vector` on the current hierarchy is downcasting. Downcasting is never guaranteed safe, so your users should *expect* that the cast might fail. You shouldn't try to cover this up even if you somehow could.

Finally, there is nothing stopping you from supplying an `AsVector3()` method to do exactly what the proposed conversion operator does.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledgeable response. What kind of vector is not a matrix?

Comment: @BrandonArnold: Actually that was meant as "not all matrices are vectors", which of course does not describe your hierarchy. So let's pretend that part never happened. ;-)